# launching chromium browser via terminal throws errors

Tags: chromium

Following these [directions](http://www.bartbania.com/index.php/build-your-own-google-tv-using-raspberrypi/) to install nodes on a Raspberry Pi

Using the following to install chrome browser

`sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`
However, after installing, when I try launching(via terminal) get the following error

```
error [1:1:1827694911:ERROR:nss_util.cc(692)] Failed to load NSS libraries.
```

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you test is using `chromium --kiosk http://www.google.com/` like it tells you in the tutorial?

Comment: according to this site https://github.com/SamyPesse/tv.js/issues/19 you can Fix the NSS Libraries issue by symlinking /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/nss/ too /usr/lib/nss

Comment: @user2005121 Have you got anywhere with this? If so, please either mark the answer that helped you, or create a self-answer with the steps you took to solve it.

Answer (score 3):

The symlinking worked for me and for my RPi, as in this worked:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/nss/ /usr/lib/nss`

Comment: You do know that you can mark a self-answer as the answer to the problem? Please mark this as such, we are trying to get the site Q:A ratio up and that would help us a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
sudo apt-get purge chromium-browser
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:chromium-daily/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

if that doesn’t work, try Steve's solution by symlinking 
/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/nss/ to /usr/lib/nss:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/nss/ /usr/lib/nss
```

Comment: tried the latter now get 2 warnings (process:2479): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
 Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(chromium:2479): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Comment: @user2005121 try this command dpkg-reconfigure locales